# Windows 10 doesn't sleep

Tags: windows-10, sleep

So, it's been a while since I had this issue and now it's getting even worse, as hitting `Suspend` button just takes me to lockscreen.

Here's what `powercfg` says about my system (it's Italian but I think it's easy to understand):

> C:\Windows\system32>powercfg /lastwake
>
> Conteggio cronologia riattivazioni - 1
>
> Cronologia riattivazioni [0]
>     Conteggio origine riattivazione - 0

As you can see there's no reason to wake up, and it's always like this (even before today's issue of going just to lockscreen).

So I tried to see which requests have been issued (again Italian, added a rough translation near each string):

> C:\Windows\system32>powercfg /requests
>
> DISPLAY:
>   Nessuna (None).
>
> SYSTEM:
>
> [DRIVER] \FileSystem\srvnet
>   Un client remoto attivo ha recentemente inviato richieste a questo computer. (An active remote client sent requests to this computer)
>
> AWAYMODE:
>   Nessuna.
>
> ESECUZIONE:
>   Nessuna.
>
> PERFBOOST:
>
> [DRIVER] Chiamante kernel legacy (Legacy kernel callee)

While the `PERFBOOST` one is quite random, the `srvnet` under `SYSTEM` is almost always there.

From my understanding this is related to home groups and media sharing, and here comes the funny part: I'm NOT into any HomeGroup, nor I do have WMP sharing enabled.

So, after following countless threads suggesting to disable things that I already had disabled, I've found out about overriding and I used this command:

> powercfg /requestsoverride DRIVER srvnet System

But, well, it didn't work at all and now even hibernation feels broken.

Can you guys please help me fixing this? It's so frustrating!

EDIT:

I forgot to mention that I already disabled wakeup for my network card, disabled wakeup timers from power management and I even disabled wakeup from UEFI settings.

Comment: Sleep is a hardware function triggered by Windows. So, there are some things you have not mentioned in your post. First and foremost, have you updated BIOS, chip-set drivers and installed all Windows updates? Is there anything running in the background which may have control preventing is from sleeping? This article, [Windows 10: PC Won’t Go to Sleep Mode](http://www.technipages.com/windows-10-pc-wont-go-to-sleep-mode), discussed multimedia settings preventing sleep. Have you checked those?

Comment: Sleep works, just not always. Everything's updated and multimedia settings are fine.